# How to delete null object inside of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have a javascript  ̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶ array which contains objects.
For example,

> [{id : '11'}, null, null, {id : '12'}, {id : '13'}, {id : '13'}]

Here I want to delete objects that are null. I have tried to loop through the     ̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶ array and deleted the null objects, but it is not traversing through the empty elements.

```
//Delete NULL elements
for (var key in objData) {
    if(objData[key].length === 0){
        delete objData[key];
    }
    if (objData[key] == null || objData[key] == undefined) {
        delete objData[key];
    }
}
```

What am I missing here ?

The object is not even traversing through the null elements.

Comment: Why not use `objData.filter`? Some people use `.fitler(Boolean)` to remove falsy values.

Comment: See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.proto.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use filter method like this and can get an updated array of objects like this:

```js
var array = [{id : '11'}, null, null, {id : '12'}, {id : '13'}, {id : '13'}];

var filtered = array.filter((el) => {
  return el != null; // here you can change condition
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: That won't catch all falsy values, just if it's null.  It could be simplified to: `var filtered = array.filter(el => el);`

Comment: @BrianBurton, yes definitely the question asks for the "null" values only.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara . It does works. But the problem is it returns only one variable which is on key[0] . And ignores the other variables.

Comment: I didn't get that "only return key[0] and ignores the other variable" what does it mean? Can you explain it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to modify the existing array instead of creating a new one, you could do that using splice.

The below solution is more flexible as it could easily be extended to delete null values in deeper nested data structures. Note that [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) does a lot of the heavy lifting in the background (e.g. delete order)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [{ id: '11' }, null, null, { id: '12' }, { id: '13' }, { id: '13' }];

const prune = (data) => objectScan(['[*]'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, property, value }) => {
    if (value === null) {
      parent.splice(property, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data);

console.log(prune(myData));
// => 2
console.log(myData);
// => [ { id: '11' }, { id: '12' }, { id: '13' }, { id: '13' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score -1):

You have to filter false values like this
[{id : '11'}, null, null, {id : '12'}, {id : '13'}, {id : '13}].filter(Boolean)

Comment: Can you explain me in brief. What is the use of filter ?

Comment: as like it says , filter filters value when one or more conditions are meet and return a new array who has been filtered.